# configure nginx to make a background request

Tags: nginx, proxy, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am building an application where I need to do some analytics on the api-data combination usage.
Below is my nginx configuration -

```
location /r/ {
    rewrite /r/(.*)$ http://localhost:3000/sample/route1/$1 redirect;
    post_action /aftersampleroute1/$1;
}
location /aftersampleroute1/ {
    rewrite /aftersampleroute1/(.*) /stats/$1;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
}
```

location `/r/` is used to redirect the browser request `http://localhost:80/r/quwjDP4us` to api `/sample/route1/quwjDP4us` which uses the id `quwjDP4us` to do something.
Now in the background I want to pass the id `quwjDP4us` to an stats api `/stats/quwjDP4us` which updates the db record for that id.

When I start nginx and make the request `http://localhost:80/r/quwjDP4us` nginx successfully redirects my request to my application but doesn't make the 2nd request in the background to the stats api. What am I missing?

Note - `post_action` is not included in nginx docs, is there an alternate module/directive I can use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you correctly mentioned, `post_action` is not documented and has always been considered an unofficial directive.

Nginx provides a new "mirror" module since version 1.13.4, described [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_mirror_module.html) in the documentation. So I advise you to give it a try. In your case, it would look like this –

```
location /r/ {
    rewrite /r/(.*)$ http://localhost:3000/sample/route1/$1 redirect;
    mirror /stats;
}

location = /stats {
    internal;
    rewrite /sample/route1/(.*) /stats/$1;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
}
```

## This will not work!

I've built a test configuration and unfortunately this will not work.  It works for neither `rewrite` nor `return`. But it works for `proxy_pass`.

## Why

The explanation follows. A HTTP request sequentially passes few "phases" during processing in Nginx. The thing is that `mirror` gets triggered in phase `PRECONNECT` which occurs later than phase `REWRITE` where `rewrite`/`return` end request processing. So, `mirror` does not even get triggered because its processing would happen later.

In case of serving files from the location or proxying via `proxy_pass` (or `fastcgi_pass`, etc), the processing will finally reach `REWRITE` phase and `mirror` will be executed.

Phases are described in Nginx documentation [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#http_phases).

## Workarounds

I do not see any good solution without trade-offs. You could create an extra location (returning a redirect) and proxy your request from `/r/`, so that `mirror` gets triggered. Something like this, depending on the rest of your configuration:

```
location /r/ {
  # you may need setting Host to match `server_name` to make sure the
  # request will be caught by this `server`.
  # proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
  proxy_pass http://<ip from listen>:<port from listen>/redirect/;
  mirror /stats;
}

location = /redirect {
  rewrite /redirect(.*)$ http://localhost:3000/sample/route1$1 redirect;
}
```

Certainly this is suboptimal and has extra boilerplate.

Comment: Didn't work. `rewrite /r/(.*)$ http://localhost:3000/sample/route1/$1 redirect;` I think the redirect flag is redirecting the request and the mirror doesn't get executed.

Comment: @JohnDoe Unfortunately, you are right. I've created a test configuration and it doesn't work. I shall update my answer.

Comment: @JohnDoe I've reached Nginx maintainers and asked them about this issue. If you are curious to read it in Russian , the conversation is [here](https://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx-ru/2018-October/061531.html). I have updated my answer with the information I've got.